# Translate and rotate a OpenGL wired sphere using values from VBO

Tags: opengl, opencl, vbo

I'm using OpenCL kernel to calculate some vertices. After calculation, these vertices (x,y,z coordinates) are updated to the OpenCL-OpenGL shared buffer.I am using NVIDIA GrForce 820m.
I need to draw a wired sphere and translate it according to the values obtained in this shared buffer.

```
void CreateVBO(){

glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,3*sizeof(vertex),pos,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

}

void Display(void)
{

glLoadIdentity();
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glPointSize(10.0);
CreateVBO();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);  
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I tried adding `glutWiredSphere` or `glutSolidSphere`. But they do not work. Also, please let me know how to make use of `translatef()`with VBO values. I need to draw a revolving sphere. Something like a moon revolving round the earth. The next position of the moon is obtained by the shared buffer. The sphere needs to be shifted by a position obtained dynamically from the VBO(openCL kernel update). Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could clarify this question a bit by supplying some images showing what you expect and what you get. "But they do not work" does not suffice in my opinion. Furthermore, why do you need to use OpenCL to translate the sphere? Doesn't a simple 4x4 matrix as a shader uniform work just fine? I understand you can use a kernel as a matrix and transform the buffer by doing so but I don't understand why you would do that other than for homework purposes. By the way, don't post the same question every once in a while. That's not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: "They do not work" means that there is no sphere rendered in the display screen. Using `glutSolidSphere` in the code makes no difference. OpenCL is used because i am trying out a sample project in parallelism. I am not using OpenCL to translate the sphere. OpenCL kernel generates (x,y,z) co-ordinates and I need to translate the sphere as per these (x,y,z) values. I would like to know your opinion on how stackoverflow works along with some valid suggestions for my problem. Thanks for replying.

Comment: First off, I'm sorry to inform you I have no experience with OpenCL (while I'm planning on looking into it someday), meaning I cannot help you with this problem. Furthermore, if you want to learn how to write good questions (which deserve good answers), you could visit the help center (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In addition, it's a terrible idea to repost a question. If you want it to receive more attention, you could add some pictures, retag it, or just improve that post opposed to actually reposting it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please observe that I am working on the same project. but my questions are different. Previously, I had a problem with OpenL-GL shared buffers. Now am having a problem in using translatef with VBO. I cannot write a new program to put forth my question. And modifying the old question to ask a new concept makes no sense.(Just because the program is same).